# R crashes when loading basemap from basemaps package

Tags: r

Creating a domain over Europe. basemap_raster requests and downloads successfully but then R crashes.

Am using R 4.3.2 and have tried with the stable and development version of basemaps.

```
library(basemaps)
library(sf)

##create simple domain of europe
d <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -25, xmax = 30, ymax = 72, ymin = 30), crs = 4326)

## get map
bg <- basemaps::basemap_raster(ext=d, map_service = "carto", map_type = "light")

## R crashes
```